# Workload must be installed, but is already installed

Tags: maui, .net-7.0

I'm running the most recent version of VS 2022 17.7.6 and .net 7.  I have a .net maui app based on .net 7.  I am getting an error when I try to build and debug my app in and run it in the android emulator.
"To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: wasm-tools"  Ok, that is strange.  I've done a dotnet workload install wasm-tools and they are showing as installed in my system.  I can't get the app to compile.  Any suggestions on getting around this error message and getting my app to compile?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1. Run `dotnet workload install wasm-tools` command in CLI/Package Manage Console.

[image]

OR Install by Modifying the VS Installer.

[image]

2. If the problem persists, try to run `dotnet workload repair` command and then restart your PC.

For more information, please check: [dotnet workload command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload) and [.NET WebAssembly build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tooling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=windows#net-webassembly-build-tools).

Comment: I have tried all of those with no luck.  I forgot to mention that I installed the VS 2022 preview for .net 8 rc2.  if I run dotnet workload list, I see all of the workloads associated the .net 8 rc2.  When I run dotnet workload repair, I always get a message about "repairing workload installation for workloads: wasm-tools"  I've restarted VS 2022.  I've rebooted, and still no love.

Comment: I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the wasm-tools, no love there either.

Comment: I just tried a repair of my VS 2022 17.7.6 and it I still get the error message.

Comment: and I just tried the VS 2022 17.8 preview, and my app comes up and runs in the android emulator.  I am guessing this is some type of issue between the release and the preview even though I'm using .net 7.0.